# PyQGIS: Problems with deleting attributes from Geopackage-Layer

Tags: pyqgis, geopackage

I am struggling with a rather simple task.
While trying to delete an attribute field from a Geopackage-Layer (Polygon and Multipolygon) I encounter results I can't understand.

My Geopackage a.gpkg contains 3 layers (test_p [Polygon], test_mp and test_mp2 [both Multipolygon]).
Each has two Features and three attributes.
They all have a projection [EPSG:25833].

I am not working in the Python shell in QGIS but in Spyder 4.1.2.
Here is my code in Python 3.7 (Windows 64) for trying to delete one of the attributes in each file:

```
from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.10/apps/qgis-ltr", True) # Path to qgis
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

####################################################
## Delete a field
####################################################

# Path to Vector Layer in Geopackage
path_list = ('E:/a.gpkg|layername=test_p',
             'E:/a.gpkg|layername=test_mp',
             'E:/a.gpkg|layername=test_mp2')

for path in path_list:
# load Vector Layer
    vl = QgsVectorLayer(path, '', 'ogr')

    # define Data Provider
    pv = vl.dataProvider()
    # delete Field with index 2
    pv.deleteAttributes([2])
    # update fields
    vl.updateFields()

# Exit Qgis Environment
qgs.exitQgis()
```

Upon examining the results in the QGIS-Browser only the layer test_mp2 was altered free of error.
The other layers show in their properties no CRS and an empty extent, although the feature count is still 2.
Yet, there are no attributes.
In addition to the corrupted files two datasets of the "no geometry"-type appeared with the filename extention "_ogr_tmp". Their attribute tables are correct, as they don't show the deleted column.

It appears to be the last handled file that results in fine order. (I checked by changing the order in path_list.)

So, if someone could explain this behaviour and suggest a solution to my problem, that would be great!

Maybe I am missing some basic understanding as I just recently started to use PyQgis and am a self-taught user of python and QGis.

Best regards
Felix

Comment: try closing the files by setting v1 = None at the end of the loop

Comment: @Ian Turton: Thanks for the suggestion.
Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything.
(I would interprete your v1 as my variable vl)

Comment: I ran your script in the QGIS Python Console (not as a standalone script) and everything works fine. I suspect the problem is either with your data itself (try recreating the gpkg and inspecting in Database Manager in QGIS?) or with running the script as a standalone package. Either way, your code & syntax is fine.

Comment: @15Step: Thanks for the confirmation. Indeed, the script runs trouble-free in the QGIS Python Console.
But my problem is, that I want it to run it in regular Python as a standalone script.